# Got blank (white) screen after build ReactJS using React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hey I'm already build my project using ReactJS with ReactRouter, but when I deploy it to my cloud server, it only brings up a blank screen, what should I do?

Here's the code in my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "react-bootstrap/Image";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/Navbar.js";
import CenteredGrid from "./components/Vids.js";
import Warta from "./components/Warta.js";
import ListWarta from "./components/WartaPage.js";
import Berita from "./components/Berita.js";
import Visi from "./components/Visi.js";
import Jadwal from "./components/Jadwal.js";
import Footer from "./components/Footer.js";
import gambar from "./images/banner.jpg";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router basename="/">
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <App />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/listWarta">
            <WartaPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/beritaartikel">
            <BeritaArtikel />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Image
        src={gambar}
        style={{
          marginTop: 80,
          width: "100%",
        }}
        fluid
      />
      <Warta />
      <Jadwal />
      <CenteredGrid />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

function About() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Visi />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

function WartaPage() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <ListWarta />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

function BeritaArtikel() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Berita />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and here's my package.json

```
"name": "gpib",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": ".",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-favicon": "^2.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

i've follow these instruction: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/
and these too: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/

Here's the console look's like [Dev Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dimKz.png)

but I still didn't get the point, and the worst part is, I don't know where I went wrong

please help :(

Comment: Hi, what errors are occurring? What is the difficulty?

Comment: Hi, there's no error, just a blank screen, i see the console there's no error's too

Comment: Is the DevTools console also empty?

Comment: It's just tell warning i believe, look's like this

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://enlmiihbdlkpihokdgndjhahhkfmfcga/include.preload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://enlmiihbdlkpihokdgndjhahhkfmfcga/include.postload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: and i'm also trying to deploy it to ZEIT Now, but i got error look's like this

Failed to compile.
16:23:19.847  
./src/App.js
16:23:19.847  
Cannot find module: 'react-bootstrap/Image'. Make sure this package is installed.
16:23:19.848  
You can install this package by running: yarn add react-bootstrap/Image.
16:23:19.873  
error Command failed with exit code 1.
16:23:19.873  
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
16:23:19.880  
Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
16:23:21.734  
Done with "package.json"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is solved when i upload it to firebase or surge, everything works smoothly, you can learn it in this article https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/